# How to triangulate phone position?

Tags: networking, tracking-devices, geo-tagging

**Description**: I am trying to create a map to see how people carrying a cellphone move inside of a given region (e.g. a building).
Since not everybody has Bluetooth or Wi-Fi turned on, I was trying to rely on the 5G network or other passive signals that would allow me to triangulate the cellphone position (lat/lon) at any given instant (t). In this way I would be able to reconstruct the trajectory.

**Question**: Are you aware of any potential project/tutorial that would allow me to achieve this task? Maybe some open source library which may include also buying some antennas or whatsover?

PS: with regards to data privacy, I am not interested in personal data rather to the position of the device which could have an anonymous id.

Comment: To be able to find the position and then track people, you would need to be able to identify the signal from each device, which would probably require a bit more decoding than just detecting a signal and a direction.

Comment: @jcaron thanks for the info. Which type of decoding are you referring to for example?

Comment: Actually decoding the signal at least (which probably uses pretty advanced modulations for any recent generation network). No idea if at that stage there is any identifier you can use to track successive transmissions by the same device, though. Otherwise you may end up needing decryption, which would normally be impossible. No idea if that would be the case or not, there’s probably at least some identifier to find the right encryption settings.

Comment: Another thing you should consider is that phones are not transmitting continuously. Given the fact it’s a pretty power-consuming activity, they actually try to transmit as little as possible.

Comment: @jcaron oh I see, I though the signal was somehow constant since I see on my phone the "signal bars" updating quite often. Ok anyways good to know, I will try to find another approach then :) Thanks anyways!

Comment: The bars are based on **received** signal levels. Reception is already quite expensive, but is a lot less expensive than transmission, so phones can afford to listen a lot more than they transmit. They need to receive quite regularly to make sure they're ready to take a call, receive an SMS... But unless there's actual data to send, phones will transmit as little as possible. They will send updates when they switch to a different cell, or one in a while to say "I'm still here". Don't know how often that happens, but IMHO it can be minutes or hours.

Comment: A final note: if by any means you are able to track back the position to a person (i.e. you get **any** unique identifier like an IMEI, IMSI, fixed MAC address, IP address...), then any such data collection is covered by GDPR, which usually means you need to get informed consent of users you track.

Comment: @jcaron yeah that is the problem. Reading in the internet I saw that it may be possible to achieve my goal by using Wi-Fi which would imply detecting the mac address of the device but I am not interested in storing it. I just need the trajectory and nothing else... so  I am not really sure if it is possible to store the information and delete the mac address right after without asking any consent.

Comment: It maybe a lot easier to use the capabilities of the wifi network, to get the approx position of a device in the building, than to try to find cell signals from the device and attempt to triangulate it. The ability to triangulate is probably built into towers to aid law enforcement, but the accuracy is in hundreds of meters. You're probably looking for atleast 10s of meters.